# Plus size wet suits?

Tags: gear, swimming, wetsuits

I know its rather ironic but I'm a big guy that enjoys open water swimming. I'd like to do more of it in order to help myself with my waistline. I swim in the Pacific so I need a wetsuit. I'm looking for specific manufacturer and model recommendations for the largest wetsuit out there. What is the absolute, hands-down largest wetsuit made?

Comment: Vote to close as this is shopping advise. However, its not uncommon for places to offer custom fit/made wetsuits - contact retailer in your area,

Comment: To enforce what mattnz said, a custom fit wetsuit may be the only way you can go. If your suit doesn't fit perfect then it's not going to work for you.

Comment: This isn't shopping advice. He's not asking for cheap wet suits, he's asking for a specific type of wetsuit. This seems resonable to me

Comment: @JimBeam no reason to be rude. Even if it's not about price, the question may be inappropriate. It's not closed blindly.

Comment: Jim - we have a 'be nice' rule. Try and adhere to that. Mods are, surprisingly enough, human, and we follow SE and community guidance. You 'despise' volunteers who try to uphold site rules? Currently, the wording does sound a lot like you want a recommendation of a particular brand, and that is explicitly off topic as per the site rules - **you** can fix that.

Comment: Just to add this would depend on style of wetsuit - full arms & legs, short cuts, no sleeves at all (good for rowers) so can you add if any particular style is required, and probably a little more helpfully where you live (this is just always handy, someone might find a custom place near you?)

Answer (score 4):

I cannot say this for all brands - as with any clothing item brands have different versions of sizing. I can be an 8 in one store but a 12 in another, go figure. I'm looking at Rip Curl as they had a great size chart.

You'll have a few factors here as having the incorrect wetsuit size can lead to a few issues like chaffing, too much gap means the wetsuit won't perform as it should do etc etc. Take measurements of your Height, Weight, Neck, Chest, Waist etc - as if you're doing a good tailored suit. Obviously it's better to find somewhere you can try one on too, as ordering online with the wrong size means returns etc, and some places may not allow returns on a wetsuit in the same way you cannot return underwear or swimming costumes (in case you wore them naked at any point).

For Rip Curl they go up to what they class as an XXL size:

- Weight: 95-105kg (209-231lbs)
- Neck: 43cm (17")
- Chest: 110cm (43.5")
- Waist: 96cm (43")

However even they state that this is a general guideline and should not be taken as anything more than approximate!

[West Coast Surf - Source](http://www.westcoastsurf.co.uk/shop/articles/sizing%20chart)

Comment: Thank you. Can I assume that XXL is their biggest size?

Comment: @JimBeam for that site in particular yes, but the difficulty here is each brand is likely to have a different chest, neck and waist size for their largest size, which could be XXL yes.